# Return inside just try

Tags: java, try-catch

I would like to ask you for advice on how to best manage this situation:

```
public Unit createUnit(final int unitLevel) {
    final List<String> widgetClassNames = getUnitsClasses();
    try {
        return (Unit) Class.forName(widgetClassNames.get(unitLevel))
        .getConstructor(Player.class).newInstance(getOwner().get());
    } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException
            | NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
```

}

This method creates a unit and returns it, but I don't like the fact that in the case of an exception I have the return null.
How can I solve it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can rethrow the error and catch it somewhere higher

Comment: What would be valid data to return in the case of an exception? If an exception is thrown, the caller is going to expect data. Or are you wanting the program to end?

Answer (score 4):

Create a new, appropriate `Exception`, which can manage custom data, such as the input `unitLevel` value.

```
public class UnitCreationException extends Exception {
   ...

   // Package-private constructor.
   // Don't expose too much to the outer world
   UnitCreationException(
        final String message,
        final int unitLevel,
        final Throwable cause) { ... }
}
```

Catch the `Exception` in-place, logging what you think might be useful information that can be accessed only at that point

```
public Unit createUnit(final int unitLevel) throws UnitCreationException {
    final List<String> widgetClassNames = getUnitsClasses();

    try {
        return (Unit) Class.forName(widgetClassNames.get(unitLevel))
                           .getConstructor(Player.class)
                           .newInstance(getOwner().get());
    } catch (InstantiationException 
            | IllegalAccessException 
            | IllegalArgumentException 
            | InvocationTargetException
            | NoSuchMethodException 
            | SecurityException 
            | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // Do not log the Exception stack-trace here, you'll do that
        // at a hihger level
        logger.error("Error message");

        // Re-throw your custom and more meaningful Exception
        throw new UnitCreationException("Error message", unitLevel, e);
    }
}
```

At a higher level, you'll be forced to catch that `UnitCreationException`

```
try {
   final Unit unit = createUnit(10);
} catch (final UnitCreationException e) {
   // Here you can log the Exception stack-trace
   logger.error("Error message", e);

   // Do something with the information contained in the custom Exception
   final int erroredUnitLevel = e.getUnitLevel();
   ...
}
```

---

There has always been a debate about checked `Exception`s *vs* `RuntimeException`s. I feel this is a good use-case for a checked one, especially if this is part of a library which can be used by multiple clients.

You'd want to be able to recover somehow from an error like that, without halting the entire application (maybe with a re-try logic).

---

I have witnessed developers using `Optional<T>` as a return type, only to avoid `null`. This is **counterproductive** as you lose the actual cause of the error, and you **cannot react** to that in its own branch (the `catch` branch)

Ultimately, Java offers you a way to customize `Exception`s, so use this feature.

Answer (score 0):

The most important thing is that your caller gets the information that the `createUnit()` call failed. You already said that `null` is a bad choice for that, and I fully agree.

The best way is to throw an exception to your caller, but which one?

- The original one?
- Or a newly-created one?

What are the aspects we should consider?

- Code readability degrades if you clutter your code with (unproductive) error-handling lines. Instead you should concentrate on what you really want to do - that's complicated enough. So, any try / catch / throw you can avoid without sacrificing robustness should be deleted.
- Your caller needs the information that the call failed, and that's what exceptions are meant for, so he should receive one.
- One problem should only be logged once, at some top level or at service boundaries. To support that, the exception should contain information for the later problem analysis. Java system exceptions already carry a good amount of useful information, but sometimes you want to add more context information. There should be no need to log errors at lower levels.
- Will the caller write code that depends on the type of exception, i.e. try/catch blocks with different reactions for different exception types? Can he even do that? Can/should he understand the inner workings of your method well enough to know what to do in this or that exception case? Normally not. So, the exception class normally doesn't matter.
- How will the application ultimately inform its user that some function failed? Can your exception help with that task, e.g. by supplying an appropriate message? But do you know what wording might be appropriate for your caller's application? So, I doubt that you can be helpful here.

So, the only reason I see for wrapping a lower-level exception in a higher-level one, is if you want to add context information useful for logging (or if some fixed method signature forces you to translate the original exception).